# ellipsis not working for long URL

Tags: css, ellipsis

Ellipsis is not working properly in case of long URL. In case of URLs, it is treating / as special character and is breaking at every occurrence of /.

```
.ui-jqgrid tr.jqgrow td 
{
   font-weight: normal; 
   overflow: hidden; 
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
   -moz-binding:url('ellipsis-xbl.xml#ellipsis'); 
   white-space: normal !important; 
   height: 22px;
   padding: 4px 2px 4px 2px;
   border-bottom-width: 1px; 
   border-bottom-color: inherit; 
   border-bottom-style: solid;
}
```

Any idea how to escape special character in ellipsis?

Comment: AFAIK, for ellipsis to work properly, we should also use `white-space`  property with other than `normal` value.

Comment: What is your HTML markup? Is the data directly in a `td` element, and is there any width set on that element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `white-space: nowrap;` in order for the ellipsis behaviour to work as you expect.

**[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/EWKAF/)**

HTML

```
<div class='ellipsis'>http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22609623/ellipsis-not-working-for-long-url</div>
```

CSS

```
.ellipsis {
    font-weight: normal;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    -moz-binding:url('ellipsis-xbl.xml#ellipsis');
    white-space: nowrap;
    height: 22px;
    padding: 4px 2px 4px 2px;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-color: inherit;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    width:100px; /* set as an example */
}
```

Comment: This is working for URL, but it is adding ellipsis for time stamp field which contains spaces and i don't want to show ellipsis in time stamp field.

Comment: Dont add the class to those elements you dont want the behaviour for?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to specify a width CSS property.

`.ui-jqgrid tr.jqgrow td {
    ...
    width: 15%;
}`

JSFiddle Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Lk55w/1/